# Worklight Adapter to connect to Advantage Database

Tags: sql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, advantage-database-server

I need to connect to the Advantage Database through worklight Adapter.
I added the adsjdbc.jar(8.1), and added the datasource definition in *SQLadapter.xml file

```
<dataSourceDefinition>
<driverClass>com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver</driverClass>
<url>jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://ipaddress:port/wxzy$/TP8/COMPANY/ABCDMAIN/ABCDMAIN.add;</url>
<user>xyz</user>
<password>12345</password>
</dataSourceDefinition>
```

When I try to Invoke the procedure, It throws

```
{
"errors": [
 "Runtime: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([Extended Systems][Advantage JDBC]Connection reset)"
],
"info": [
 ],
"isSuccessful": false,
"warnings": [
]
}
```

Kindly advice.

## Thanks

Thanks @Idan,
I tried with a Java Program to connect, before trying with the adapter as below,

Class.forName("com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver");

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:extendedsystems:" +
        "advantage://port:host//abcd$//TP8//COMPANY//XYZMAIN//XYZMAIN.add;user=xxxx;password=123456");
 statement = connection.createStatement();
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from USERS");
while (resultSet.next()) {
 System.out.println("PS USER NAME :"+ resultSet.getInt("PS_USERNAME"));
}
```

But I get a com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSException: [Extended Systems][Advantage JDBC]Connection reset

Please Advice.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Anybody has any idea

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that problem is in the JDBC URL value.

You have set the following:
`<url>jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://ipaddress:port/wxzy$/TP8/COMPANY/ABCDMAIN/ABCDMAIN.add;</url>`

But in the documentation it gives this example:
`("jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://server1:6262/test/data;user=user1;password=up1");`

So if I were you I'd check why you used the JBDC URL that you've used there, which does not seem to be inline with the product doucmentation of Advantage Database.

Comment: Hi @Idan, can you please comment on the edits I've made.

Comment: That's a problem with the connection to the database, not with adapters. I do not have the answer to that.

Comment: Ok Noted, I understand there is some connectivity problem, but kindly let me know if I need to connect to a datasource, should i try with the the connectionPolicy in adapter.xml file or add the datasource in server.xml.

Comment: If you are looking to use an adapter, you need to edit the adapter's XML file.

Comment: Instead of asking, just try. Note that the URL structure does not seem valid to me, but I cannot tell you what is valid. Just try.

Comment: if i change it like this in adapter, Is this correct  <dataSourceDefinition>
         <driverClass>com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver</driverClass>
         <url>jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://ip:port/abcd$/TP8/COMPANY/XYZMAIN/XYZMAIN.add;user=xxxxx;password=12345</url>
      </dataSourceDefinition>

Comment: I get adapter deployment failed, if i try with this URL. Anyways thanks