# Connecting to Remote Advantage Database server from Java

Tags: java, jdbc, advantage-database-server

We are migrating a project from Dotnet to Java. The connection string in dot net is as follows

```
Data Source=\\ip:port\timesoft$\TP8\COMPANY\KCLMAIN\KCLMAIN.add;ServerType=REMOTE;User ID=ITUSER;SecurityMode=IGNORERIGHTS;Password=123456;
```

In Java we have written a test program to check the connectivity, which is a follows

I have added the adsjdbc.jar (v8.1)

```
Class.forName("com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:extendedsystems:" +
    advantage://ip:port/timesoft$/TP8/COMPANY/
    KCLMAIN/KCLMAIN.add;user=ITUSER;password=123456");
```

or with catalog

```
Class.forName("com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:extendedsystems:" +
advantage://ip:port;catalog=//ip:port/timesoft$/TP8/COMPANY/
KCLMAIN/KCLMAIN.add;user=ITUSER;password=123456");
```

But it throws connection reset error, please suggest what is wrong.
Also, I'm not able to set the SecurityMode=IGNORERIGHTS; and ServerType=REMOTE; in drivermanager.getconnection. if we pass these it says unknown parameter.

Comment: Hi, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596528/worklight-adapter-to-connect-to-advantage-database

Comment: Thanks for your time @mvlaicevich. That was raised by me too for worklight adapter side

Comment: Please post the actual connection string you use, as shown by the syntax highlighting you have mangled something. Note that in a lot of JDBC drivers the separator is a `&`, the `;` is not always supported as a property separator.

Comment: And looking at http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html the properties `SecurityMode` and `ServerType` don't exist and seem to be specific to the .NET driver which supports some type of local/embedded version of Advantage.

Comment: Still Working on this. will update once i find a solution. Thanks for your support.